# Trying to set host name with AWS ec2 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hostname

So here's the deal, I'm trying to run a little webmail server for testing purposes off amazon's EC2 server, I'm looking at their guide for setting the hostname, and the directory they mention /etc/sysconfig/ doesn't exist, let alone the file I'd be expected to edit, when I go to the actual hostname file (as if I was running the server) cd /etc/ then nano hostname I can read but I don't have write permission, so when I go to save the file it tells me I don't have the permissions, so I looked it up, and it says to edit /etc/sysconfig/network which would be fine and dandy, if the directory actually existed. Pretty new to all of this, so if I missed anything that could help you figure out what's going on please let me know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using sudo? Or making sure to ssh as admin?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the base AMI you are using for your instance is not one of Amazon's AMI's. What AMI is the instance based on?